# Simple app works correctly on Android Emulator but crashes on a real device

Tags: android, opengl-es

Real Device: LG G2, android 4.4.2, OPENGL ES v3.0

Emulated Device: Nexus 5X, android 7.1.1, OPENGL ES v2.0 (Hardware)

Apps that involve modifying the views (setting text, making views visible/invisible, etc) run flawlessly on the emulator, but crash on the real device **(on button press)**.

Apps that don't involve modifying any of these work fine on the real device.

I've tried it with this simple app:

(activity_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cmnd97.test.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="method"
        android:text="Press me" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(MainActivity.java)

```
package com.cmnd97.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    protected void method() {
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setText("Pressed");
    }
}
```

This particular app crashes on button press without printing any error message to the debugger, however another app which involved hiding/showing a button printed this error:

Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR  error=EGL_BAD_MATCH

Comment: `protected void method()` - This is a problem. When you specify an `onClick` attribute in the layout, the method it refers to must be `public` and have a `View` parameter - `public void method(View v)`.

Comment: apparently, this was the root of all problems. No more opengles errors, everything works perfectly. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file and gradle you need to set the minimun sdk target, so in your case could be works sdk 15 or 16

`defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }`